# Is accessing a non-existent member NOT considered an "error" as far as SFINAE is concerned?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I've implemented an overload for pretty printing pairs:

```
template<typename P>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const P &p) {
  using std::operator<<;
  os << '(' << p.first << ", " << p.second << ')';
  return os;
}
```

However, in its presence the compiler has trouble telling whether it should apply the standard overload or the one I've defined above, even in cases when the choice *should* be obvious:

```
int main() {
  cout << "SFINAE sure is hard to grasp!\n";
}

error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is
      ambiguous (with operand types 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and
      'const char [30]')
```

I don't quite understand what the problem is. The char array I'm trying to print clearly has no `first` or `second` members, so instantiating it with my overload would result in an error.

Shouldn't SFINAE try to perform the substitution, find out that a member is lacking, and discard the result? If not, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) works during overload resolution:

> This rule applies during overload resolution of function templates: When substituting the explicitly specified or deduced type for the template parameter fails, the specialization is discarded from the overload set instead of causing a compile error.

That means only the signature of function templates will take effect for SFINAE, the implementation won't be checked.

You can change the overloading to

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct pairable : std::false_type {};

// check whether type T has first and second members
template <typename T>
struct pairable<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().first),
                               decltype(std::declval<T>().second)>>
    : std::true_type {};

// the template parameter is the part of the signature of function template
template<typename P, std::enable_if_t<pairable<P>::value>* = nullptr>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const P &p) {
  using std::operator<<;
  os << '(' << p.first << ", " << p.second << ')';
  return os;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0kfbnqB408LZoKEQ)

Comment: A bit simpler, not needing SFINAE: `template <typename P1, typename P2> ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, std::pair<P1, P2> const& p);`...

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes you're right; anyway I fixed my sample, as OP said *has no `first` or  `second` members*, so checking whether the type cantains `first` and `second` members might make it more general.

Comment: Well, no (*'anyway'*), my comment was intended as *additional* information, showing up a simpler *alternative*... My version handles `std::pair` only, yours is more generic, which can be preferrable (until we once discover a type having another member `third` we want to print out as well...).

Answer (score 5):

SFINAE applies only to function signature: i.e. argument types, the return type, and qualifiers, such as: `const`, non-`const`. It does not apply to implementations of functions.

In your case, the function signature matches the call. Hence, the function is instantiated, and is expected to compile without errors.